# Can't identify this transformer [80LL 19T-6-L G HI POT LI - TAI B-19 0614 OK]

Tags: power-supply, transformer, identification

This is the power supply of my old lcd monitor, the transformer is burnt.

I have difficulties to find the correct model, I've googled about it without success (maybe I'm using the wrong keywords). The person at electronics shop told me that he can't identify the model.

Do you know this transformer? Where can I find the datasheet?

here the code that is print on it

```
 80LL 19T-6-L   G   HI POT
 LI TAI B-19   0614     OK
```

thanks

[image: the transformer]

[image: the power supply]

Comment: The transformer in a product like this is unlikely to be a standard unit you could buy off the shelf. In any case, appliance repair questions are off-topic here.

Comment: The transformer itself is hardly ever the root cause of a failed switching power supply. If it is burnt, it's very often just a consequence of at least one other faulty part. Hint: Try to make your question less specific, and it may be a good fit for this site. ("What may be the reason for a SMPS transformer to burn?" or something along that line) As it stands, you can expect votes to put it on hold. The reason is that a question as specific as yours is not valuable for other users in the future ("too specific").

Comment: On a different note, that transformer doesn't _look_ burnt.

Comment: Montor troubleshooting: Does it turn on? If no, replace power board. If yes, shine a flashlight on it to see if backlight system is faulty. If backlight system is faulty, repair/replace backlight system. If no, replace control system and repeat last test. Your transformer is fine.

Comment: I'm with John: it doesn't look burnt. How do you know it's broken?

Comment: A bad capacitor, the big one in the picture, broke the power supply circuit somehow. I'll figure out how to fix it, thank you. Sorry for the off topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a custom Li Tai power transformer: [their standard offerings](http://www.litai.com/transformers.htm).

You will need to contact them to get more information.